# awk to update unknown values in file using range in another

Tags: awk

I am trying to modify an `awk`kindly provided by @karakfa to update all the `unknown` values in `$6` of `file2`, if the `$4` value in `file2` is within the range of `$1` of `file1`. If there is already a value in `$6` other then `unknown`, it is skipped and the next line is processed. In my awk attempt below the final output is `6 tab-delimited fields`. Currently the `awk` runs but the `unknown` vales are not updated and I can not seem to solve this. Thank you :)

**file1** (space delimited)

```
chr1:4714792-4852594 AJAP1
chr1:4714792-4837854 AJAP1
chr1:9160364-9189229 GPR157
chr1:9160364-9189229 GPR157
chr1:15783223-15798586 CELA2A
chr1:15783224-15798586 CELA2A
```

**file2** (tab-delimited)

```
chr1    3649533    3649653    chr1:3649533-3649653    .    TP73
chr1    4736396    4736516    chr1:4736396-4736516    .    unknown   
chr1    5923314    5923434    chr1:5923314-5923434    .    NPHP4
chr1    9161991    9162111    chr1:9161991-9162111    .    unknown
chr1    9162050    9162051    chr1:9162050-9162051    .    rs6697376
```

**desired output**
--- the second and fourth unknown values are updated based on the range that they fall in `$1` of `file1`

```
chr1    3649533    3649653    chr1:3649533-3649653    .    TP73
chr1    4736396    4736516    chr1:4736396-4736516    .    AJAP1  
chr1    5923314    5923434    chr1:5923314-5923434    .    NPHP4
chr1    9161991    9162111    chr1:9161991-9162111    .    unknown
chr1    9162050    9162051    chr1:9162050-9162051    .    rs6697376
```

**current output with awk**

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{
                       rstart[a[1]]=a[2]
                       rend[a[1]]=a[3]
                       value[a[1]]=$2
                       next} 
 $6~/unknown/ && $2>=rstart[$1] && $3<=rend[$1] {sub(/unknown/,value[$1],$6)}1' hg19.txt input |    column -t
chr1  3649533  3649653  chr1:3649533-3649653  .  TP73
chr1  4736396  4736516  chr1:4736396-4736516  .  unknown
chr1  5923314  5923434  chr1:5923314-5923434  .  NPHP4
chr1  9161991  9162111  chr1:9161991-9162111  .  unknown
chr1  9162050  9162051  chr1:9162050-9162051  .  rs6697376
```

edit:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{split($1,a,/[:-]/)
                       rstart[a[1]]=a[2]
                       rend[a[1]]=a[3]
                       value[a[1]]=$2
                       next} 
 $6~/unknown/ && $2>=rstart[$1] && $3<=rend[$1] {sub(/unknown/,value[$1],$6)}1' hg19.txt input |    column -t
```

**possible solution to issue 2:**

----- matching `$2` values in `file1` are combined with the first lines `rstart[a[1]]=a[2]` being the start and the last lines `rend[a[1]]=a[3]` being the end

```
chr1:4714792-4837854 AJAP1
chr1:9160364-9189229 GPR157
chr1:15783223-15798586 CELA2A
```

Comment: Is it safe to say that file1 and file2 are both *whitespace* delimited, or is it possible that file1 will include tabs within fields, or file2 will include spaces within fields?

Comment: `file1` is 2 whitespace delimited fields, while `file2` is 6 tab-delimited fields.  Thank you :).

Comment: this script is wrong!  you're not splitting the first field in the first file. so array a is undefined, (what is a[1]?)  But more important: the key in first file is not unique and will be overwritten for each row.

Comment: I added a `split` that may work but not sure about your second, definitely more important.  Thank you :).

Comment: I added a possible solution to the second issue, though I am not sure how to implement it.  Thank you :).

Comment: in my actual data of 3500 records the script updates about half with values. I believe the others that remain `unknown` do not fall into the first match found.  I will post an example as well.  Thank you :).

Comment: Thank you very much, the others were just not in `file1`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another script (it's inefficient since does a linear scan instead of more efficient search approaches) but works and simpler.

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{split($1,a,"[:-]"); k=a[1]; c[k]++;
                           rstart[k,c[k]]=a[2];
                           rend[k,c[k]]=a[3];
                           value[k,c[k]]=$2;
                           next} 
        $6=="unknown" && ($1 in c) {k=$1; 
                             for(i=1; i<=c[k]; i++) 
                                if($2>=rstart[k,i] && $3<=rend[k,i]) 
                                   {$6=value[k,i]; break}}1' file1 file2 |
 column -t
```

since it's possible to have more than one match, this one uses the first found.

```
chr1  3649533  3649653  chr1:3649533-3649653  .  TP73
chr1  4736396  4736516  chr1:4736396-4736516  .  AJAP1
chr1  5923314  5923434  chr1:5923314-5923434  .  NPHP4
chr1  9161991  9162111  chr1:9161991-9162111  .  GPR157
chr1  9162050  9162051  chr1:9162050-9162051  .  rs6697376
```

note that the fourth record also matches based on the rules.